# Rx 6600xt stuck on Motherboard splash screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, amd-graphics

(I am Dualbooting)
I recently replaced my Radeon R7 260x with an Rx 6600xt and was hoping it would work without further changes because they are both AMD gpus , but after switching the GPU ,the system gets to the point where you can choose your Os but not any further. When choosing linux as the boot option it shows the Motherboard splash screen again and gets stuck there.
The GPU seems to be functional though , because when choosing Windows it works just fine.

I updated to Ubuntu 21.04 , but that didnt really help. Any help would be great :D

(I still have the old Gpu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is missing firmware. The system actually boots fine, it's just that there is no video (see last paragraph). I was able to fix the issue by updating the kernel to the latest stable mainline release, and by installing the missing AMD GPU firmware files.

What you need to do is this:

1. `git clone  git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git` I assume here that you run this in your user's home dir.
2. `cd /lib/firmware`
3. `sudo mv amdgpu amdgpu.orig`
4. `sudo cp -r \~/linux-firmware/amdgpu ./` This assumes you cloned the above linux-firmware in your home dir.
5. Install latest kernel from `mainline` (I used 5.13.12) - if you need a tutorial see [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/). Make sure initrd gets regenerated as part of the kernel install. If it doesn't, you may need to run `sudo update-initramfs -k all -u`

That should do it.

How did I figure it out? Installed `openssh-server` on my box, then let the 5.13.12 kernel boot and sshd into my box. Ran dmesg and saw that amdgpu driver was complaining of a missing firmware file  `/lib/firmware/amdgpu/dimgrey_cavefish_sos.bin`. Check to see if it's in `/lib/firmware`. Figured that the kernel Pop OS 21.04/Ubuntu 21.04 ship with don't have this firmware, and the mainline kernel installer doesn't bother updating the `linux-firmware` package, so I had to get it off git...

Comment: Why installing it from git when You can install it using apt? Like so `sudo apt install linux-firmware`?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz the reason why you need the git version, is because the package version lacks the firmware necessary to initialize the latest release of the amdgpu kernel module with a rx6000 series GPU. That’s the root cause of the issue.

Comment: It looks like I have it `ll /lib/firmware/amdgpu/dimgrey_cavefish_sos.bin` and I only installed firmware using apt. I am using RX 6800 XT btw. Nowthing wrong with Your solution I was just curious why go that route.

Comment: Do you have a problem with your GPU? You can always try the SSH method (run dmesg) to figure out what the amdgpu module is complaining about.

Comment: No, mine works fine.

Comment: Oh, interesting… yours works fine with Ubuntu 21.04/Pop OS 21.04? Do you mind sharing your linux-firmware package version and uname -r output? Just curious….

Comment: linux-firmware is 1.197.3, kernel is 5.13.13. Ubuntu is 21.04.

Comment: Noted! Looks like Pop OS packages its own, version is 1.197.1. I can update to 1.197.3 and see the diff… thanks for the tip!

Comment: Confirmed! The Pop OS linux-firmware package lacks a bunch of firmware files, actually.